# Add type definition for type not used in any api method

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an api end point that takes a custom header.
This header is a object that looks like this:

```
User: {"UserId":"someguid"}
```

If I have the type as a parameter in a api method I can do as follows:

```
public class AddFileParamTypes : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.operationId == "FileDelivery_Post")
        {

            operation.consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "file",
                required = true,
                type = "file",
                @in = "formData"
            });
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "User",
                required = true,
                schema = new Schema() { @ref = "#/definitions/User" },
                @in = "header"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But the User type will not be a parameter for a method, so how do I add the definition to swashbuckle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, it was simple but lacking in documentation:

```
public class AddFileParamTypes : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.operationId == "FileDelivery_Post")
        {

            operation.consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "file",
                required = true,
                type = "file",
                @in = "formData"
            });
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "User",
                required = true,
                schema = schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(typeof(User)),
                @in = "header"
            });
        }
    }
}
```